# Сумма столбца таблицы с учетом количества

Tags: php, mysql

Всем доброй ночи. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в запросе посчитать сумму столбца умноженное на количество? То есть, в таблице есть два столбика в одном кол-во, в другом цена. Нужно в запросе умножить цену наколичество в каждой строке и просуммировать.

Comment: Например [так][1]...


  [1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78b4c5/1

Comment: напиши запрос здесь пожалуйста, а-то я с телефона

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select sum(col1*col2) from table

Comment: Сперва так и сделал, но выдало ошибку, но косяк был у меня в коде. Так что, отлично, заработало!